# What are the arguments given by non Sri Vaishnava schools that the Pancharatra Agamas are non-Vedic?

Tags: vaishnavism, shaivism, agamas, pancharatra, shaiva-siddhanta

Please give arguments from any school.

Please also cite from scholarly works.

Comment: Could you change to question to remove the 'Shaivites' tag to make the question more generic? An argument from a vaishnava is also valid. Is there any specific need for the refutation to come from a shaiva school of thought?

Comment: Non-Vedic means anti-Vedic?

Comment: You are supposed to reply to comments asking for clarification. If Non-Vedic= Which is not found in the Vedas, then there is absolutely nothing to prove. If it means not in line with Vedas, then there can be arguments.

Comment: @Rickross I mean not in line with Vedas and if it contradicts the Vedas.